# Where can I Find translation for Error Logs in PG?

Tags: postgresql

I have noticed in a French cluster intallation that some messages and codes written are in french (not for all). I need to know the correspondances of english version and french version of these informations.
Someone give me this page : https://babel.postgresql.org/
But in the file "[postgres.pot](https://babel.postgresql.org/)" the entries for error classes (WARNING, ERROR, FATAL, PANIC...) is empty :

```
#: utils/error/elog.c:3243
msgid "STATEMENT:  "
msgstr ""

#: utils/error/elog.c:3636
msgid "DEBUG"
msgstr ""

#: utils/error/elog.c:3640
msgid "LOG"
msgstr ""

#: utils/error/elog.c:3643
msgid "INFO"
msgstr ""

#: utils/error/elog.c:3646
msgid "NOTICE"
msgstr ""

#: utils/error/elog.c:3650
msgid "WARNING"
msgstr ""

#: utils/error/elog.c:3653
msgid "ERROR"
msgstr ""

#: utils/error/elog.c:3656
msgid "FATAL"
msgstr ""

#: utils/error/elog.c:3659
msgid "PANIC"
msgstr ""
```

So the question is : is there any table in PG where I can find the corresponding translation between english version and locale version of;

```
error or warning messages
severity code (FATAL, PANIC, ERROR...)
```

?

Or any file if no table...

Example of error file I have :

```
023-11-27 00:00:23.557 CET [40408] ATTENTION:  autovacuum worker started without a worker entry
2023-11-27 00:00:49.203 CET [53116] ATTENTION:  autovacuum worker started without a worker entry
2023-11-27 00:02:35.898 CET [12100] ATTENTION:  le worker de l'autovacuum a pris trop de temps pour démarrer ; annulé
2023-11-27 00:03:38.703 CET [12100] ATTENTION:  le worker de l'autovacuum a pris trop de temps pour démarrer ; annulé
```

Comment: Set `lc_messages = C` so that your log file and your error messages are in English.

Comment: @Laurenz_Albe, OK, but this is a workaround, not the answer.... Doesn't PostGreSQL have any way to get this translation into sql or command line like pg? Because I can't always impose such modifications for my customers...

Comment: I am aware that that is not the desired answer, so I made it a comment. There is no way to automatically translate the messages. You'd have to look at the `*.po` files in the source, and the messages contain placeholders. Only superusers can change `lc_messages`. If your clients are configured to use a different setting for that parameter, you have a problem. Therefore my recommendation to keep that setting to `C` everywhere.

Comment: @Laurenz_Albe, as I mentionned, in the question there is no entries in the postgresql.po file for error classes like : STATEMENT, DEBUG, LOG, INFO, NOTICE, WARNING, ERROR, FATAL, PANIC

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry for misunderstanding. I will write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The strings that denote the message levels (`ATTENTION` in your case) are determined by the `lc_messages` locale setting on the database server. There is no SQL function to translate them. For a translation, you'll have to look at the appropriate PO file in the PostgreSQL source. In the case of French, that would be [`src/backend/po/fr.po`](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/po/fr.po), where you will find the following lines:

```
#: utils/error/elog.c:3324
msgid "WARNING"
msgstr "ATTENTION"
```

That means that the (default) English message `WARNING` will be shown as `ATTENTION` in French.

My recommendation is to always use `lc_messages=C` to get your log files in English. That way, you get the best results if you use a web search to learn more about an error message.

Here is a list of labels and their translation:

| English | French |
| --- | --- |
| DETAIL | DÉTAIL |
| HINT | ASTUCE |
| QUERY | REQUÊTE |
| CONTEXT | CONTEXTE |
| LOCATION | EMPLACEMENT |
| BACKTRACE | PILE D'APPEL |
| STATEMENT | INSTRUCTION |
| WARNING | ATTENTION |
| ERROR | ERREUR |

Comment: @Laurenz_Albe there is no such file in the pg "cluster". Installation of my customers are on windows. I did not find any file in the install directory... And as I say it is impossible to change the behaviour in production server of my customer...

Comment: My mistake, I was sloppy. The file is in the source. I understand that you cannot just change the configuration for the customer, but perhaps you can suggest it to the customer (I am aware that French speakers might not want that). Anyway, you have to look up that information only once, since it is not subject to change. I have compiled a list of translations for you.

Comment: @Laurenz_Albe I'll do that with a CTE in future dev when dealing with CSV formated error messages to be recover from files... Thanks. But I do not SE FATAL nor PANIC....

Comment: They are the same in French and English, as is `DEBUG` or `INFO`.

Comment: I don't see any translation for  : STATEMENT, DEBUG, LOG, INFO, NOTICE. PANIC word does not exists in french. It is PANIQUE...

Comment: `STATEMENT` is in my list. The others are identical in the French translation. You could start a discussion about "panique" on the [pgsql-translators](https://www.postgresql.org/list/pgsql-translators/) mailing list, but that's how it is currently.